# Wheezy RC1: Bug Report?: “Oh No! Something Has Gone Wrong.”

Tags: linux, gnome, thinkpad, debian

I got a new Thinkpad T430 but had all sorts of hardware/driver issues with Debian Squeeze since it's outdated. Major issues - wireless wasn't working after numerous attempts, yadayada.

So I upgraded to Wheezy RC1 and most of those issues were solved. I've had some issues like random freezes but nothing that prevented me from working..until today.

Yesterday I downloaded some JRE packages and today upon heading to work the Wireless wasn't able to connect to the network at work.. my old thinkpad was able to perfectly. After restarting, I get: "Bug Report?: “Oh No! Something Has Gone Wrong.”" after logging in and selecting Gnome/Gnome Classic and it asks me to login again, and this becomes an endless loop.

I can access other ttys in console mode. I can create a new user and login to Gnome, but how can I solve this for my primary user?

Here is xsession-errors.

http://static.arounds.org/xses.txt

Also, I had display issues and wasn't ever able to legitimately install drivers through nVidia - I believe I need to do this, but I've never had issues logging in even without doing that.

Would appreciate any help.

**Edit:** upon using another username all day i logged in as my original and when trying to 'filezilla&' it gives me:

```
Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

So this is the root of my issue, as I predicted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with Debian Wheezy RC1 + Thinkpad T430 and when you disable Touchpad while typing, it completely breaks things. I re-enabled and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `xhost +` before executing anything as a different user.

What about moving all gnome configuration files? Save them with another name an try logging with a clean home.